# bash: cannot create temp file for here-document:read-only file system

Tags: bash

When I am I'm entering my password after entring loging I'd then **-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document:read-only file system** is coming.
Please help.

Comment: This happen often when there is a problem at boot. Cloud you give us the output of `dmesg` ?

Comment: Hello Hemant. Please add the output of `ls -ld /tmp` and `mount | awk '$3=="/" || $3=="/tmp"'
` to your question. Don't put updates here in the comments but instead [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/725161/edit) to include the information _as if you had thought of doing it yourself in the beginning_.

Comment: Simply reboot your OS